# Exception: type '_AsBroadcastStream<List<DocumentSnapshot<Object?>>>' is not a subtype of 'Stream<List<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>>

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, geohashing

Full Android Studio Logcat complaint:

> Dart Unhandled Exception: type
> '_AsBroadcastStream<List<DocumentSnapshot<Object?>>>' is not a subtype
> of type 'Stream<List<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>>'

I'm using [GeoFlutterFire2](https://pub.dev/packages/geoflutterfire2/example) plugin, which strives to query Firebase on a Geohash.  Well no longer!  My attempts to update `pubspec.yaml` to a more recent [cloud_firestore](https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore/changelog): ^3.1.4
seems to have precipitated this, so I rolled cloud_firestore back to ^2.5.4

```
      setUpJobStream(double _distanceFromUser) {
        localJobsStream = geo
            .collection(
            collectionRef: myFirestore
                .collection('GB/Edinburgh/JobsDetailed'))
            .within(
            center: usersAddressGeoFirePoint,
            radius: _distanceFromUser,
            field: 'position',
            strictMode: true);
    
        localJobsStream.listen((List<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String,dynamic>>> documentList) {
          if(documentList.isNotEmpty) {
```

...
I tried the obvious thing and simply switching localJobsStream.listen parameters to:
`localJobsStream.listen((List<DocumentSnapshot<Object?>> documentList) {`
But it didn't work :/

This is all quite depressing really. Feel I should be the boss of this one, help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The type returned has changed. IT now returns a **Object?** instead of **Map<String,dynamic>** I had the same issue using a stream transformer.

Replace **List<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String,dynamic>>>** with **List<DocumentSnapshot<Object?>>**